# Why my image doesn't load on contentPane except on CENTER?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layout-manager, border-layout

I am currently still learning Java GUI and stumped on this problem. I just wonder why can't i load it anywhere except on center and how do i load my image anywhere else?

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Player player = new Player();
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        JButton button = new JButton("shock me");

        panel.add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, player);


        //frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, player);

        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's my player class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Player extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Image image = new ImageIcon("Source/hero.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, 3, 4 , this);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Image image = new ImageIcon("Source/hero.jpg").getImage();`  1) Potentially long running operations should be kept out of any paint method.  Instead declare it as an attribute of the class and load the image once when an instance is constructed. 2) That way of loading an image presumes a `File` path, but that won't work for deployment, better to start working with an `URL` right now. 3) `ImageIcon` won't return errors if it does not find / cannot load the image.  Better to use `ImageIO` which throws an informative exception if there is a problem.

Comment: 4) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { ..` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ..`.  Always call the `super` method first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Player` does not override `getPreferredSize()` to return a value.  Since it does not do that, the `BorderLayout` will not assign it any height in the `PAGE_START` or `PAGE_END` constraints, and no width in the `LINE_START` and `LINE_END` constraints.  The component ***is*** being added, it just has no width/height.

The `CENTER` will stretch both a component's width and height to the available space, that is why it is visible there.